# Can I use Ext.JS's APIs in Sencha Touch?

Tags: javascript, iphone, android, extjs, sencha-touch

This question seems silly. But I'm new to javascript and sencha touch.

Can I use Ext.JS's APIs in Sencha Touch backed project? I find Ext.util.Cookies is only in Ext.JS, not in Sencha Touch. Can I use it in my project~

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be able to use Ext JS functionalities as long if you link the good javascript part in your page and if the script you use don't render anything in the page(or it's going to be messy).

Ext JS and Sencha touch are both javascript framework simply they don't aim for the same device but since the android phones have some normal web browser most of both framework would probably works.

The cookie feature should work, so you just have to link the ext js library and use whatever part of the API you want.

i.e you probably have to you html file

```
<script src="/where/ever/you/have/ext.js"></script>
```